# Braintree custom paypal button

Tags: php, paypal, braintree

I would like to create a drop-down list for payment methods.

For example:

```
<ul>
  <li id="paypal">paypal</li>
  <li id="credit_card">credit card</li>
</ul>
```

On select credit card, it loads all fields needed for credit card payment. But now I am having trouble setting up a paypal button. I don't really want a blue button. Can I have the user click id="paypal" and launch paypal?

```
  braintree.setup(token,"custom",{
    paypal:{
      container:"paypal",
      amount: 10.00,
      currency: 'USD'
    }
  })
```

Can I make it completely custom looking? I want the paypal button just look like an item in the list with my CSS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Braintree employee here. As of [2.15.0](https://github.com/braintree/braintree-web/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#2150), we introduced a "headless" option that allows a custom PayPal button.

This work is live at these JS urls:
https://js.braintreegateway.com/js/braintree-2.15.2.js
https://js.braintreegateway.com/js/braintree-2.15.2.min.js

We created a [small gist](https://gist.github.com/danielwu426/70eac6b34ab7491610f0) that provides sample code. This version is not yet hotlinked but our docs will be updated when it is.

Comment: Thank you, keep up the good work. This makes things much nicer. 8)